# How to add key value pair to django queryset

Tags: python, django

I want to show stats for account by account in for loop of template. In list of dicts or querysets.

I have 3 models: (1)AdvertisingAccount, (2)Campaign, UserProfile. 
I need to sum() clicks and views of Campaigns that belongs to certain AdvertisingAccounts by Foreign Key. (AdvertisingAccount also belongs to UserProfile )

Im trying to retrieve, calculate and add new key-value to dicts of queryset, but seems like I cant do it in dict method…

**views.py**

```
def ad_accounts(request):

    user = request.user
    accounts = user.userprofile.advertising_accounts.all()

    accounts = accounts.values()

    for d in accounts:
        d.update(('clicks', d.campaigns.all().aggregate(Sum('clicks')) )  for k,v in d.items())
        d.update(('views', d.campaigns.all().aggregate(Sum('views')) )  for k,v in d.items())
```

**models.py**

```
class AdvertisingAccount(models.Model):
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    foreign_system_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, default=None)
    foreign_system_id = models.IntegerField(default=None, blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.foreign_system_name + '--' + str(self.foreign_system_id)


class Campaign(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey('users.UserProfile', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='campaigns')
    trade = models.ForeignKey('payments.Trade', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='campaigns')
    ad_account = models.ForeignKey('AdvertisingAccount', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='campaigns')
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    clicks = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    ad_spent = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.userprofile) + '--' + str(self.ad_account.foreign_system_name) + '--' + str(self.trade.ad_budget)
```

**template**

```
{% for i in accounts %}
  {{i.clicks}}
  {{i.views}}
{% endfor %}
```

I got error :`'dict' object has no attribute 'campaigns'`

As I cant retrieve filtered data from templates, Im trying to construct custom queryset or list of dicts. Does the whole way correct? How to solve my problem?

Comment: Why are you using dicts to begin with? What is the point of the `values()` call?

Comment: Was trying to access dict methods instead of queryset

Comment: @George: although `.values(..)` has a certain value (for some complicated aggregates, etc.), usually it is better to use model objects as much as (reasonably) possible. A `Campaign` object is not the same as a dictionary that carries fieldnames and values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please do *not* annotate manually, you can simply use Django's [**`.annotate(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate). You even used a generator here where it will result in querying *a lot* of times for a single `Account` model.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

accounts = user.userprofile.advertising_accounts.annotate(
    clicks=Sum('campaigns__clicks'),
    views=Sum('campaigns__views')
)
```

The above will generate a `QuerySet` of `AdvertisingAccount`s, and with extra attributes `.clicks` and `.views`. The error is in fact entirely because you did not use `AdvertisingAccount`s in the first place, but dictionaries (that originate from the `.values()`, and you thus lose the context of the relations).

The annotation will run in a single query, where Django will make a query that looks like:

```
SELECT advertising_acount.*,
       SUM(campaign.clicks) AS clicks,
       SUM(campaign.views) AS views
FROM advertising_acount
LEFT OUTER JOIN campaign ON campaign.ad_account_id = advertising_acount.id
GROUP BY advertising_acount.id
```

This is more efficient than aggregating *per* `AdvertisingAccount`, since then you would hit the database *2n+1* times here with *n* the number of `AdvertisingAcount`s.

Usually it is therefore nearly always better to use model instance over a dictionary: a model class allows you to define methods, properties, it will add relations, etc. It also holds the type of the object (for example an `AdvertisingAccount`) whereas two dictionaries with the same keys do not per se originate from the same models. A dictionary is just a flat stucture that maps field names to the corresponding database value. You thus "lose" a lot of context.